# Logging exception for a fire and forget task in a transient lifetime service

Tags: c#, multithreading, logging, task, unity-container

I have a fire and forget task, that I need to report some telemetry in, it doesn't matter if the task succeeded or not (that's why it's a fire and forget), but I needed to make sure that's not blocking the api call.

When an exception is raised in the telemetry task I log the exception.

My code goes something like this:

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private readonly IReporter reporter;
    private static readonly Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    public MyService (IReporter reporter){

    }
    //..
    public Task<Result> processorRequest()
    {
        // ...
        _ = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            reportTelemetry();
        });

        //...
    }

    private void reportTelemetry()
    {
        try
        {
            reporter.Report();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Warn($"An exception was raised while reporting: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

The logger is created at the top like so:

```
private static readonly Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

`MyService` and the `Reporter` are created and injected to the container with the **transient** lifetime.

**My questions are:**

Will the reference to logger in the new thread prevent `MyService`/`Reporter` from being collected? Or will the GC decide to free the service even before `logger.Warn` is called?

Do I risk not reporting the exceptions for some reason (besides app shutdown)?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will the reference to logger in the new thread prevent MyService/Reporter from being collected?

No, but the reference to `this` will ensure the service is kept alive until the delegate has started running. The lambda will essentially be rewritten to

```
public class MyHiddenDelegate{
    private MyService service;
    public MyHiddenDelegate(MyService service) => this.service = service;
    public void Execute() => service.reportTelemetry();
}
```

And this object will be referenced by the stack of the executing thread, or the task-queue. But the `logger` does not really play any part regarding the lifetime of any object since it is a static field.

> Or will the GC decide to free the service even before logger.Warn is called?

The GC has to keep object alive until the last usage of any reference. So the service might be eligible for collection before the call to `logger.Warn`, since it does not need the `this` reference to access the logger. But this is normally fine since the GC will ensure nothing is collected before the last usage.

One exception might be if you own native resources. Then you might need to use [GC.KeepAlive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.keepalive?view=net-5.0) to ensure the finalizer is not run before you are done with the native resource.

> Do I risk not reporting the exceptions for some reason (besides app shutdown)?

Not due to any collection issues as far as I can see. But there might be other considerations, like uncatchable exceptions.